# extracting hexadecimal value from hexadecimal data

Tags: c++

I have hexadecimal data as \x83, which represents that it is a hexadecimal data.
I want to get the value 83. I have down the following steps.

```
char *has = "\x83";
unsigned long num;
char *endptr;

num = strtoul(has,&endptr,8);
```

Which is not the correct solution. Let me know how to get the hexadecimal value by neglecting the hexadecimal representation.

Regards,

Comment: You want to get the value 83 in what base?

Comment: Why base 8 and not base 16 ???

Comment: \x is not stored in memory, has[0] = 0x83, please refer the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057258/how-does-x-work-in-a-string

Answer (score 4):

You're mis-interpreting what you have. This:

```
char *has = "\x83";
```

defines a 1-character long string, consisting of the 8-bit value 0x83 (131 in decimal) (followed as always by the `'\0'` terminator).

This is not something you need to convert using `strtoul()`, it's already there in binary.

Just do:

```
const unsigned int num = ((unsigned char *) has)[0];
```

And you're done.

You would have used `strtoul()` if the value was really there as hex in the string:

```
char *has = "0x83";
```

But that is a totally different situation.