# Why are are these re-cast string types returning different data?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm reading a 'qbytearray' string from a text file that I don't have control over.
I'm not using Qt.

But this way of handing the string in the text file works in my program:

```
unsigned char* apa = (unsigned char*)"\xf1`\xf9\a\\\x9cT\x82z\x17\x5\xb9\xbc\x60\xca\x15";
```

but this does not work:

```
unsigned char* apa = (unsigned char*)settings_in.at(1).c_str();
```

(yep I have double checked the contents of the std::string settings_in)

Why are these different?
And how could I achieve the top result with a std::string?

UPDATE: Ok so based on your comments here's more info:
I'm reading a Qt generated textfile with the line,

```
1\rp_key=@ByteArray(\xf1`\xf8\a\\\x9cT\x82z\x14\x5\xb9\xbc\x80\xca\x15)
```

I'm stripping out the long string inside the parenthesis.
I'd love to not recast but Iv'e tried so many things that hasn't worked and that seemed to get me somewhere.

The goal is to fill in this variable,

```
uint8_t rp_key[0x10] = {0};
```

The hard coded 'ground truth':

```
unsigned char* apa = (unsigned char*)"\xf1`\xf8\a\\\x9cT\x82z\x14\x5\xb9\xbc\x80\xca\x15";
printf("No1:  %s\n", apa);
```

and std::string code that prints out the same string as above but in ascii (unicode?) format:

```
std::string str = settings_in.at(1);
unsigned char* thing = (unsigned char*)str.c_str();
printf("No2:  %s\n", thing);
```

Hm I'm not sure what I can write that proves the contents of my 'settings_in'. I just tried this:

```
char *cstr = "\xf1`\xf8\a\\\x9cT\x82z\x18\x5\xb9\xbc\x80\xca\x15";
std::string str = cstr;
unsigned char* thing = (unsigned char*)str.c_str();
printf("No2:  %s\n", thing);
```

but that's no good as the result works in my program. Is that proof?
(please ignore the actual contents as I'm altering it since the original is sensitive)

This also works in the program,

```
std::string str = "\xf1`\xf8\a\\\x7cT\x82z\x14\x5\xb9\xbc\x80\xca\x15";
unsigned char* thing = (unsigned char*)str.c_str();
printf("No2:  %s\n", thing);
```

Comment: what's the type of `settings_in`? If it is `std::string` then how can you call `c_str()` on `settings_in.at(1)`?

Comment: *yep I have double checked the contents of the std::string settings_in* -- We need to see it -- if you are the only one checking, you can look at the code a thousand times and not pick up on an error if you are not aware that an error exists.

Comment: The other thing is that you should never have to cast string types.  That is an instant code-smell.  Either use the correct string type, or call the function that accepts the type you are working with without having to cast, or create / rewrite the functions so that they work with your string type without casting.  If you must cast, you better have a great reason to do so.   If you're casting just to shut-up the compiler from giving an error, then that is the wrong approach.

Comment: Added updated comments in the OP.

Comment: Oh wait no it's not right. It's not actually working.  But the 'No2' printout prints the ascii of the data in the No1 example.

Comment: You still havent told us what settings_in is. That was comment 1.

Comment: See [example]. Make sure that we can reproduce the problem with only the code in the question

Comment: For instance, if `settings_in` is a `std::string` then you can directly initialize it with the value that you would have in your program (without having to go through `qbytearray` or something similar)

Comment: I think that's what I did im my last update?

Comment: Nope, I only see that you said that you didn't figure out to make a [example].

Comment: Well if thats not enough to understand the problem then I don't know. I thought the original question was pretty clear.
I guess that means that you all think the the original two cases are equivalent as you can't tell from them what's wrong.

Comment: As explained in the page, post a complete program that shows the issue. (although the issue might be [c++ - Why does calling std::string.c_str() on a function that returns a string not work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980664/why-does-calling-stdstring-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-wor)

Comment: I can't prove that two things are the same when my problem is that the two things are not the same. And that I illustrate with examples above.
I don't think its the same as the issue you linked as I don't get garbage out.

Comment: @RedMarsBlueMoon `char *cstr = "\xf1\xf8\a\\\x9cT\x82z\x18\x5\xb9\xbc\x80\xca\x15";` -- That is not valid C++ code, since the type has to be `const char *`, not `char *`.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7ec40b01eed6e7b).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   Ok it might not be valid but so far the only thing that has worked for me. I'm open to suggestions.    [I show it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ed8ace76785af0)

Comment: [Here is another example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9443304ad369564)
I don't understand why I can't get the std::string to behave like the char*

Comment: Hmm I think maybe I messing up when I'm passing the data from my function that reads the text file.
I was printing for verification inside the function and that was good.  But now when I'm printing the data from after using the function it looks incorrect!
I'm hoping that's what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: No that was not it. But it somehow gets scrambled as I pass out or return the data. I need to get some sleep now so have to try again tomorrow.
This is my file reader:
std::vector<std::string> ReadSettings();
and
std::vector<std::string> ReadSettings()
{ 
    std::vector<std::string> out_strings;
   //printing good here
    return out_strings;
}

then where I use it:    
std::vector<std::string> settings_in = ReadSettings();

Comment: Nope its not getting scrambled either. I think its got to do with how C/C++ treats the operator '\x'.  When reading in from the file the '\x means hex' functionality is dropped. While when I hard code initializing with that string it gets 'correctly' interpreted as a hex number. I still haven't figured out how to get around that. (if that's actually it)

Comment: "The translation is done at compile-time so that every string you manually enter into the source code with \x and such ends up being the character it represents in the binary. If you want to do this at run-time you will need to invoke a parse function like strtol() using base 16 passing the string containing the hex and cast it to a char."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057258/how-does-x-work-in-a-string

Comment: Yep that's the one I linked in the comment just above yours! :)
I also answered my own question with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put this here as the answer from another overflow Question:

> The translation is done at compile-time so that every string you
> manually enter into the source code with \x and such ends up being the
> character it represents in the binary. If you want to do this at
> run-time you will need to invoke a parse function like strtol() using
> base 16 passing the string containing the hex and cast it to a char.

[How does "\x" work in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057258/how-does-x-work-in-a-string)

This matches perfectly what's happening.

The suggestion of how to emulate at runtime doesn't seem to apply to my case though.